# Can't connect to Mssql server running in docker container on Mac from CLI or pyodbc - Azure DS works?

Tags: python, sql-server, bash, macos, docker

I am currently unable to connect to a MSSQL server I have running in a docker container on my mac laptop using any CLI tools or pyodbc. Connecting to, and interacting with the database with pyodbc is the goal. Strangely, using Azure Data Studio I can connect without issue.

I followed the following two tutorials to install Sql server on my mac, and then restore an old backup of an existing server.

https://database.guide/how-to-install-sql-server-on-a-mac/
https://database.guide/how-to-restore-a-sql-server-database-on-a-mac-using-azure-data-studio/

Microsoft's suggested sqlcmd statement did not work for me

```
    sqlcmd -S <ip_address>,1433 -U SA -P '<YourNewStrong!Passw0rd>'
```

that was documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017&pivots=cs1-bash

- when I first installed docker, I did not increase the memory allocation to 4GB. I did so after my container was running and restarted the container and the mac itself. My understanding is that that memory should be available to that container now.
- I have tried mssql, sqlcmd, pyodbc with various connection parameters, but none of them are working for me.
- I CAN connect through Azure Data Studio with the following connection information: 
  Connection Type: Microsoft SQL Server
  Server: localhost,1401
  Authentication type: Sql Login 
  Username: sa
  password:

Based on my success interacting with the database through ADS, I've been assuming that there are errors with the connection parameters I'm passing to the CLI tools, but at this point I think I've tried just about every permutation I can think of. I've included some connection attempts and the errors they throw.

I have read many other github and stack overflow tickets, it looks like the usual causes of this issue are people not running their container or not using a sufficiently complicated PW. That does not appear to apply in my circumstance.

```
$ sqlcmd -S 172.17.0.2,1433 -U SA -P <TestPW123$>
```

Result:

```
SqlState HYT00, Login timeout expired
HResult 0x102, Level 11, State 0
TCP Provider: Error code 0x102
HResult 0x102, Level 11, State 0
A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
```

---

```
$ sqlcmd -S localhost,1433 -U SA -P <TestPW123$>
```

RESULT:

```
sqlcmd(992,0x112ef45c0) malloc: can't allocate region
*** mach_vm_map(size=18446744073709527040) failed (error code=3)
```

---

```
$ mssql -s localhost -o 1433 -u sa -p <TestPW123$>
```

Result:

```
Connecting to localhost...
Error: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1433
```

Comment: could you please try two things 1) check to see if the sql server process is running, if running, is it listening use ps -ef & netstat -an 2) use single quotes to give password or give password on the next line. I hope you are not typing angle brackets :)

Comment: running 'ps -ef' inside the docker container produces the following:
'''
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 14:55 ?        00:00:02 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
root         8     1  2 14:55 ?        00:03:07 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
root       870     0  0 16:53 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
root       884   870  0 16:53 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
'''

running netstat -an inside the container produces an error: 
'''
bash: netstat: command not found
'''
I was not adding angle brackets, and entering the PW on another line or using single quotes didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this by creating a new docker container and restoring the database to that container, I was never able to figure out what the previous issue was, but CLI tools are all working now.

I followed the Microsoft tutorial carefully, and when trying to connect from outside the container, i used the internal network IP of my laptop. In my case it was 192.168.0.4, not the 127.0.0.2 IP's that some tutorials referenced. I did wrap my password in single quotes on the successful connection. Here's the successful connection:

'''

```
sqlcmd -S 192.168.0.4,1433 -U SA -P 'TestPW123$'
```

'''

hopefully this helps someone else.